# Entity Framework tutorial (simple code-first example) doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Today I started following an Entity Framework tutorial: [Simple Code First Example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx)

I think I have everything how it should be, but my application doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {

    }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }

    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
    {
        public Standard()
        {

        }
        public int StandardId { get; set; }
        public string StandardName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
        {
            Student stud = new Student() { StudentName = "New Student" };

            ctx.Students.Add(stud);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("done.");
        }
    }
}
```

It builds without any errors or warnings, console starts, but it doesn't go past

```
ctx.Students.Add(stud);
```

It also didn't create any database and tables.

I followed everything from the tutorial, and have no idea why it doesn't work.

EDIT:
It does throw an errorafter 60 seconds (Additional information are in polish, I don't really now how to change it to english in VS):
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Wystąpił błąd związany z siecią lub wystąpieniem podczas ustanawiania połączenia z serwerem programu SQL Server. Nie można odnaleźć serwera lub jest on niedostępny. Sprawdź, czy nazwa wystąpienia jest poprawna i czy konfiguracja serwera programu SQL Server zezwala na połączenia zdalne.  (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Błąd podczas lokalizowania określonego serwera/wystąpienia)

And I have to add, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community and the localDB which is included in this version of visual studio.

Comment: I can't see your connection string, you must provide it in your context.

Comment: Sorry, link works now. In tutorial there's nothing about connection string

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx check it out.

Comment: "Doesn't go past...".  What does this mean, exactly?  Is there an error message?  If so, it'd help to know what it is...

Comment: @SaeedHamed Providing the connection string is not required if the default is good enough for you, and the tutorial intentionally makes use of the default. As for your link, I'm sorry, but I really don't see how that is even remotely helpful.

Comment: There's no error, I just put Console.WriteLine before and after the Students.Add statement. The one before is printed, the one after is not.

Comment: Does the text "done" get printed?  If it does not, you probably have an exception getting thrown somewhere.  Have you run the code in the debugger?

Comment: The one at the end of using statement is not printed. It is printed to console only if I put it in before Students.Add. I builds without any errors. When I debug it, also there are no errors.

Comment: When you debug your code, does your code actually complete? You say that you don't get any exception, but also that the statements at the end don't get executed. That shouldn't be possible if your program finishes, no matter how abnormally. Does your debugger show that the program has stopped, or is it possible that the program hangs or appears to hang? If the program does hang or appear to hang, how long did you wait? Some exceptions involve time outs and involve waiting at least half a minute before you get details about what went wrong.

Comment: There is an error, sorry I didn't know it can't take that long for it to show. I edited my post.

Comment: So, can't connect to the database server.  What is the connection string (show the app.config).

Comment: There is no connection string. It wasn't created on it's own, and tutorial didn't say anything about it so I didn't create it.

Comment: I will recomend you this [tutorial.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) Here everything is explained really well.
[Tutorial Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make your navigation properties as virtual? Also if you want to connect this two Student and Standard class to each other you need to define foreign keys.

For example add this in Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {

    }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }

    public int StandartID{get;set;}//foreign key references Standard(StandardId)
    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }//navigation property
}
```

And this in Stadart class:

```
public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {

    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public int StudentID{get;set;}//foreign key references Student(StudentID)
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this will help you